# In an «ask turtles» method: How can I read a variable of a patch in a relative angle and distance from a turtle?

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I want [turtles with [shape = "sheep"]] to move either to the lefthand side or the righthand side, depending on how many [attractive (green) patches] are around a certain relative patch.

[How the turtles with [shape = "sheep"] should count the patches (yellow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSJOG.png)

The (incorrect) code looks like this:

```
to move-sheep
  ask turtles with [shape = "sheep"] [
    right random (16 + (count neighbors4 with [pcolor = green] patch-right-and-ahead 60 2)^ 2)
    left random (16 + (count neighbors4 with [pcolor = green] patch-right-and-ahead -60 2)^ 2)
    forward 1
    #(some other commands…)
  ]
end
```

Thank you ^^

Comment: Your image has all the turtles at the same angle relative to the patches and identical patches surrounding each target patch. I can't work out what you are trying to count. I suggest you simply ask the `patch-right-and-ahead 60 1.5` to change colour to red (or similar) to debug.

Comment: "I can't work out what you are trying to count" - @JenB
Look at the embedded Link.

Comment: I did look at the embedded link, which is a pretty image with no text description of what anything represents. There are dark yellow and pale yellow (green?) patches. Are you counting both or just the dark yellow? What are the rules for a patch to be counted (or not). For example, between two angles, no more than X distance away, must have the four NSEW patches all green and not the diagonal neighbours. You are asking us to help with code about counting patches without providing the rules that you want followed, or a description of what is going wrong with your current code.

Comment: Okey, I want to count the yellow squares at the left hand side as well as the yellow squares at the right hand side (But, as you may see, each side for a different line).
I want to replace those «count neighbors4 with [pcolor = green] patch-right-and-ahead ±60 2» with the number of [yellow visualised patches] with [pcolor = green]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier if you actually told us what the problem is. You say your code is wrong, but not how you know it's wrong. Is it reporting an error (and, if so, what is the error and which line is reporting it)? Is the moving turtle going the wrong way?

Regardless, the easiest way to approach this is to do something smaller before trying to move. If you simply count the number of green patches and print that out, you can test the code. Once you introduce movement, how will you tell if it counted correctly?

I am still not entirely sure what you are asking. But I think this code might help you diagnose your problem. It tells you what the count is around the target patches, so you can see if it is doing the correct count. Once you know the counting works, you can then modify for movement.

```
to testme
  clear-all
  ask patches [set pcolor one-of [yellow green]]
  create-turtles 1 [set heading 30 set color black]
  ask one-of turtles
  [ ask patch-right-and-ahead 60 2 [set pcolor red]
    type "Right: "
    print count ([neighbors4] of patch-right-and-ahead 60 2) with [pcolor = green] 
    ask patch-right-and-ahead -60 2 [set pcolor red]
    type "Left: "
    print count ([neighbors4] of patch-right-and-ahead -60 2) with [pcolor = green]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Ouf… Well: The agents are sheep and they should turn towards that side where more grass is. (But including RNG)

Comment: And the «count neighbors4 with [pcolor = green] patch-right-and-ahead 60 2» was meant to show what has to be count. @JenB

Comment: Have you tried the code I provided? If it counts the correct things, you can use the agentset construction code I wrote and place it inside your movement lines. If it counts the wrong things, what are you trying to count instead? If it's not the counting that is the problem, what is the problem?

Comment: Omg it works;                                                                                                                                                                                 
right random (16 + (count ([neighbors4] of patch-right-and-ahead 60 2) with [pcolor = green])^ 2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
left random (16 + (count ([neighbors4] of patch-right-and-ahead -60 2) with [pcolor = green])^ 2)

Comment: @Trummler - If Jen's answer has solved your issue, please click the check mark near the top of their answer to accept it and mark this question as closed.